# React Native ScrollView scrolling both directions

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to get a React Native ScrollView to scroll horizontally and vertically, but for some reason it won't do it. I know it doesn't work on Android, but it is supposed to work on iOS.

I've looked at this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2962

And did what it suggested, but it still only scrolls one direction.

This is how I have it declared:

```html
<ScrollView directionalLockEnabled={false} horizontal={true} style={styles.container}>
    {this.buildContent()}
</ScrollView>
```

Any ideas on how to get this to scroll both directions?

Comment: As far as I know this is only possible by setting contentContainerStyle to fixed size. Some more information that might help you [#8579](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8579)

Answer (score 7):

There is currently not a direct way to achieve this. If setting *contentContainerStyle* prop is not a problem for you, you can go that way. If it is, you can always use 2 nested *ScrollViews*.

```
<ScrollView>
   <ScrollView horizontal={true}> 
      {this.buildContent()}
   </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
    <ScrollView
      maximumZoomScale={2}
      minimumZoomScale={1}
      style={{ width: 320 }}
      contentContainerStyle={{ width: 321 }}
    >
      <View style={{ width: 321, height: 320, backgroundColor: "green" }} />
    </ScrollView>
```

[contentContainerStyle Doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#contentcontainerstyle) here,the property supported officially from `react-native@0.9`

Comment: I could never guess something called `contentContainerStyle` will effect the scrolling gesture but it actually **works**, **but** only for iOS, Android still only works either vertically or horizontaly at a given scroll gesture, also on iOS it has some weird lagging at the beginning of the drag but it is good enough in my case, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me.

```
<ScrollView
    horizontal
    bounces={false}
>
    <ScrollView
        nestedScrollEnabled
        bounces={false}
        // You will need to figure out the height of inner content yourself
        contentContainerStyle={{ height: calculateHeight() }}
    >
        <View>
        ...
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```